# NativeScript-Angular -> ActionBar in app.component.ts is not consistent when the route changes

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular-router

this is the app.component.html

```
    <ActionBar title="NewApp" class="action-bar font-awesome">
        <ActionItem (tap)="toggleDrawer()" ios.position="left">
            <Button text="&#xf039;" class="font-awesome" id="menu-btn"></Button>
        </ActionItem>
    </ActionBar>

    <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

When route changes The action bar changes to something else. Can't I use ActionBar in app.component.ts ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you use `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` instead of `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>` you will get the results you are expecting.

`<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>` replaces the entire page, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will only replace the content block

Comment: But item-details component is not rendering when the items is is preseed from the item list(initial page) but it is initializing. And hardware back button is not working.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/1441#issuecomment-434132592

Add Following to main.ts

```
 platformNativeScript({ createFrameOnBootstrap: true})
 .bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

nativescript has changelog readme for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can use the ActionBar in app.component.ts

here is a basic example:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
  <ActionBar title="Glossary" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`,
  styleUrls: ["app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When route changes the ActionBar changes to
```
<ActionBar title="NewApp" class="action-bar font-awesome">
</ActionBar>
```
Note that action item is lost in new route. I'm not using ActionBar in new route template. But the ActionItem inside it is lost.

Comment: There is possibly a property not being cleared when the route changes occur. Can you please share your components, html and service?

Comment: here is my github repo url. Please see the files init. https://github.com/bunnyvishal6/example-nativescript-app